# operate on c++ 11 variadic template parameters, store into tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic

I'm trying to learn a bit of c++ 11 with variadic template arguments.

I want to take a list of floating point input arguments to convertTest(), then return an std::tuple of ints. I try to compile the following in g++:

```
template<typename ...ArgsIn, typename ...ArgsOut>
static inline std::tuple<ArgsOut...> convertTest(float nextArg, ArgsIn... remainingArgs)
{
    auto a = convertTest(remainingArgs...);
    auto b = std::make_tuple(int(nextArg));
    auto c = std::tuple_cat(a, b);

    return c;
}

static inline std::tuple<int> convertTest(float lastArgIn)
{
    return std::make_tuple((int)lastArgIn);
}

int main()
{
    auto res = convertTest(0.5f, 10.11f);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 error: conversion from 'std::tuple<int, int>' to non-scalar type 'std::tuple<>' requested
```

I'm not sure why the return type `std::tuple<ArgsOut...>` would resolve to `std::tuple<>`. Any ideas?

I've tried making the return type `auto`, but I get complaints about missing trailing return types in that case.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"I've tried making the return type `auto`"*, for that one C++11 requires trailing return type (i.e `auto foo() -> returnType {/*...*/}`). C++14 allows to have simply `auto foo() {/*...*/}` and so to deduce the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Argout`are non deducible, so become empty list.
So you would have to write the function in that order instead

```
template<typename ... ArgsOut, typename ...ArgsIn>
static std::tuple<ArgsOut...> convertTest(float nextArg, ArgsIn... remainingArgs);
```

And call it

```
convertTest<int, int>(0.5f, 10.11f);
```

BTW, you may simply write it like (removing the fact that you take exclusively `float`)

```
template<typename ...Args>
auto convertTest(Args... args)
-> decltype(std::make_tuple(static_cast<int>(args)...))
{
    return std::make_tuple(static_cast<int>(args)...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!